# Error Code 1215 foreign key en mysql

Tags: sql

Estoy teniendo problemas con tres FK. Es una relación N:N que apunta a sus PK . Todas tienen el mismo tipo (SMALLINT)

Esta es la tabla dónde tengo que poner esas FK

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS result(
municipalityID SMALLINT,
districtID     SMALLINT,
sectionID      SMALLINT,
tableID        SMALLINT,
partyID        SMALLINT,
provinceID     SMALLINT, 
votes          INTEGER,
```

Tabla que tiene las PK y quiero que sean FK.

```
introducir el código aquí
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  tableElection ( 
municipalityID  SMALLINT,
districtID      SMALLINT,
sectionID         SMALLINT,
tablesID        SMALLINT,
possibleVotes   INTEGER,
totalVotes      INTEGER,
nullVotes       INTEGER,
blankVotes      INTEGER,
pollingstationID SMALLINT NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT pk_tableElection PRIMARY KEY 
(municipalityID,districtID,sectionID,tablesID), 
CONSTRAINT fk_tableElection_pollingstation FOREIGN KEY 
(pollingstationID) 
                         REFERENCES pollingstation(ID) 
                               ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE

);
```

Sólo he tenido problemas con esas tres FK. Las estoy añadiendo con esta sentencia

```
ALTER TABLE result
ADD FOREIGN KEY (districtID) REFERENCES tableElection (districtID);


ALTER TABLE result
ADD FOREIGN KEY (sectionID) REFERENCES tableElection (ID);


ALTER TABLE result
ADD FOREIGN KEY (tableID) REFERENCES tableElection(tableID);
```

Y me sale un "ERROR CODE 1215 CANNOT ADD FOREIGN KEY CONSTRAINT" . ¿Porque me da este error si tengo la tabla creada y el tipo de dato coincide?

Gracias!!!

Comment: Podrias indicar que error te esta dando? o cual es tu problema

Comment: ¿Todas las columnas que son FK existen realmente con el nombre indicado en sus tablas y son del tipo `smallint`?

Comment: He reformulado la pregunta, todas son smallint

Comment: @RaulCacacho me da un error (1215) al insertar la FK

Comment: un detalle también importante es que las tablas que llevan las foreign keys se crean hasta el final, es decir primero van las tablas que tienes llaves primarias y al final las llaves foráneas

Comment: @AlfredoPaz están creadas hasta el final

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que puedas crear tus tablas, deberías hacerlo en el orden siguiente idealmente:

```
CREATE TABLE pollingstation(
    id SMALLINT NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(100)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS result(
municipalityID SMALLINT,
districtID     SMALLINT,
sectionID      SMALLINT,
tableID        SMALLINT,
partyID        SMALLINT,
provinceID     SMALLINT, 
votes          INTEGER
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  tableElection ( 
municipalityID  SMALLINT,
districtID      SMALLINT,
sectionID         SMALLINT,
tablesID        SMALLINT,
possibleVotes   INTEGER,
totalVotes      INTEGER,
nullVotes       INTEGER,
blankVotes      INTEGER,
pollingstationID SMALLINT NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT pk_tableElection PRIMARY KEY (municipalityID,districtID,sectionID,tablesID), 
CONSTRAINT fk_tableElection_pollingstation FOREIGN KEY (pollingstationID) REFERENCES pollingstation(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

Yo solo agregué al inicio una tabla de ejemplo, para complementar el ejercicio y de este modo te evitas los comandos de `ALTER TABLE`